# What is considered a "large" Flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Or what is the largest you've worked on?  (In terms of number of files, number of "views", or any other useful metric.)

Comment: I voted to close as this is not a technical question.

Comment: I'm aware it's not "objectively" answerable, but nevertheless I'd like to hear opinions. It's an honest question. IMO that's all that matters.

Comment: Please read the FAQ for the type of questions this site targets: http://stackoverflow.com/faq .  To quote relevant passage: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to agree with Jeffry (sorry I think I called you Joshua a couple of times), how do I vote to close, just flag and it doesn't belong here?

I will however offer you my current project stats for the time being though since I wrote up a maven plugin to count this all out and I don't get to use it often (this is not necessarily the largest I've worked on but I would consider it fairly large).

```
[INFO] I saw 2325 files and 1044 directories while walking the tree
[INFO] I saw 1157 files that were not svn related.
[INFO] Number of '.as' files: 694
[INFO] Number of '.mxml' files: 137
[INFO] Number of '.css' files: 6
[INFO] Number of '.java' files: 0
[INFO] Number of '.jar' files: 1
[INFO] Number of '.xml' files: 39
[INFO] Number of '.prop' files: 0
[INFO] Number of '.png' files: 224
[INFO] Number of '.gif' files: 0
[INFO] Number of '.jpg' files: 0
[INFO] Number of '.swf' files: 8
[INFO] Number of '.swc' files: 1
[INFO] Number of '.html' files: 8
[INFO] Number of '.js' files: 20
[INFO] Number of '.class' files: 0
[INFO] Number of '.properties' files: 0
[INFO] Number of '.prefs' files: 3
[INFO] Number of svn related files (svn-base, all-wcprops, entries, tmp): 1168
[INFO] Number of other files: 16
[INFO] That took about 3373 milliseconds to figure out
```

Comment: If you have enough reputation; there is a "close" button between "Edit" and "Flag."  I'm not sure how much reputation is needed to vote to close, though.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com awesome thanks for clarifying for me, just got up to 3000 points and got the privilege to mark for close, I agree this isn't really a programming question and I don't understand its usefulness really so marking it to be closed as well.  I'll leave my answer here for the time being anyhow unless you or others in the community find it to be obstructive.